# jQuery Stop .animate for few second and play another animate

Tags: jquery

I'm new for jQuery and I need some help to done this small code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


   $('.cartoonsmart_right').animate({top: "-50"},500)(stop for few second and play another .animte).animate({top: "-400"},500, function() {$('.head_monkey1').removeClass("none")  .animate({left:"120"});});

 } );
 </script>
```

Comment: I try already before but it not work

Comment: How different between

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  


******************************************************


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
*****************************************************************


The Top One it not work but the bottom one is working I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `.delay()` method.

> **jQuery.delay()**  Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

#### Sample

```
$('.cartoonsmart_right').animate({top: "-50"},500).delay(2000).animate(...)
```

#### More Information

- [jQUery.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: Thank you all, I love this Place.

Comment: @moreinet Glad to help! Stackoverflow is awesome. Please consider to accept my answer, but only if my answer was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `.delay()`, or use function callback chaining, ie:

```
$(".cartoonsmart_right").animate({top: "-50"}, 500, function() {
   $(".other_element").animate({ ... }, 1000, function() {
       $(".yet_another_element").animate({ ... }, 750, function() {
          ...
       });
   })
});
```

Each new function is called when the old one finishes.

Comment: Thank you all, I love this Place.

Comment: Try falling in love with the green tick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `delay()`. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cartoonsmart_right')
    .animate({top:"-50"}, 500)
    .delay(1000)
    .animate({top: "-400"}, 500, function() {
        $('.head_monkey1').removeClass("none").animate({left:"120"});
    });
});
```

Since you move elements by absolute position values you need to make sure you set the following CSS property on them:

```
position: absolute;
```

Without it it won't work!

Full working demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cartoonsmart_right')
    .animate({top:"-50"}, 500)
    .delay(1000)
    .animate({top: "200"}, 500, function() {
            $('.head_monkey1').removeClass("none").animate({left:"120"});
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="cartoonsmart_right" style="position:absolute">CartoonSmart</p>
<p class="head_monkey1 none" style="position:absolute">Headmonkey</p>
</body>
</html>
```